# How can I make the background colour of a list item 'stay' red once it or any of it's children are active?

Tags: html, css

I understand how to make the background red on hover but how do I keep only the top list items on a horizontal menu with a red background once any of the child menu items nested inside it are active?

Here is a link: http://www.weblabdigital.com/

Comment: this is not how this works. Show us some code you tried out and we'll help you out with it.

Comment: show some effort, we can guide you, not do your job, here's a tip, maybe you're looking for: [focus](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus)

Comment: thank you for assistance.... I tried to add my code but I keep getting an error preventing edit update, this site is very hard to use.. It says "Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above." I look to see where the error and there is no message about any error?? Just leaves me on a dead end... I try pasting my code in here and it says its too long... I press enter to break up my comment and I cant even do that... I cant believe a programming site like this offers such a troublesome experience...

Comment: read and look what the error is trying to say

Comment: there is a CSS way for background-color, give us your code and what you tried, so i can give you an example from your code using your active class

Comment: it says in a strange position on the right side - your code does not appear to be formatted as code. Please use 4 spaces.... I even tidyed it up in jsfiddle before pasting it in and still rejects it... It doesnt even like jsfiddles standards? why does this site makes life so difficult???

Comment: put you fiddle link here in comments, i can edit your question then if you like

Comment: Here is a link to my site... seems to be giving me a nightmare when adding code into this question... http://www.weblabdigital.com/

Comment: just saw it, you have no class setted on any active links when you go from a page to another. It is not aCSS matter here :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand... What is the solution in laymans terms? Should I add or take away something?

Comment: add the **code** not the site link

Comment: @user3368643 well, depends how you generated your page. If it is via a server script, add a class where you need to see highlights., If it is HTML page home made, add manually a class to each page you are making. Maybe you should delete this question or reformulate it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to target elements in the wrong direction. CSS cascades, which means that you are styling down the DOM, not up. Basically, you can't style an elements parent without using javascript or dynamically generating your navigation with, say, PHP. [Shaun Inman suggested a specification for a parent selector](http://shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors) that would allow parents to inherit from their children, but there are tons of issues with this methodology.

As an alternative you could, instead, try a javascript solution. Here is one with jQuery:

```
// Find current page links
var nav_current_page = $('.navigation a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]');

// If found links
if (typeof nav_current_page !== 'undefined') {
    // Add class of active
    nav_current_page.addClass('active');

    // Target parent LIs and add active
    nav_current_page.parents('li').addClass('active');
};
```

This will add an active class to the current page and all of it's parent `<li>` elements. You can then style the navigation to keep the background red when the `.active` class is present. This is not a highly optimized solution, but it will get the job done.